# scala: list of dates to list of ranges

Tags: scala

I've got something like this:

```
case class Range(start: String, end: String)
List("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4")
```

and I want to get:

```
List(Range("s1","s2"), Range("s2","s3"), Range("s3", "s4"))
```

For sure I can use classical java for-based solution but I looking for something more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you expect

```
list.sliding(2).collect { case List(from, to) => Range(from, to) }.toList
res0: List[Range] = List(Range(s1,s2), Range(s2,s3), Range(s3,s4))
```

Here is another option

```
(list zip list.tail) map Range.tupled
```

Comment: Grate! Sliding is what I looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Łukasz, `Range` is an object, not a function, and `Range.apply()` is overloaded so there's ambiguity when trying to get it `.tupled`.

Comment: You are right about all that but here, I use `Range` case class defined by OP, not scala `Range`, hence there is no overloads and everything compiles, I tested it in repl. Unless I am missing something here?

Comment: Maybe it is my fault, I should provide more meaningful names. Anyway this solution does the job.

Comment: Oops. Missed that.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution that works regardless of the type of your data (which you can map to whatever you want afterwards):

```
scala> val l = List("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4")
l: List[String] = List(s1, s2, s3, s4)

scala> l.dropRight(1) zip l.drop(1)
res4: List[(String, String)] = List((s1,s2), (s2,s3), (s3,s4))
```

Cheers

Comment: Nice, but you can save a traversal of `l` by skipping the `dropRight`.  It comes up with the same result.

Comment: @jwvh Cool, haven't noticed that!

Comment: `drop(1)` is a `tail` operation actually. Expected result contains `Range`s, not tuples.

Comment: Hi @Łukasz, thanks for the observation, it's even more concise now:

`l zip l.tail`

I didn't map it to a Range, since I just wanted to demonstrate the idea, but that's easy enough:

`scala> (l zip l.tail) map { t => Range(t._1, t._2)  }
res25: List[Range] = List(Range(s1,s2), Range(s2,s3), Range(s3,s4))`

Cheers

Comment: Łukasz, just saw you added it to your answer, nice use of tupled, well done. Cheers